# Is my use of Lagrange multipliers correct?

Tags: optimization

Given $n$ positive values. $x_i \ge 1 (1\le i \le n)$. Their sum is $k$.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = k
$$
Define the following value:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(x_i-1)
$$

Now use Lagrange multipliers to find when this value is minimum.

Define $J = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(x_i-1) + \lambda ((\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)-k)$. Then $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x_i}=0$ implies that $x_{i} = -\frac{(\lambda-1)}{2}$. Substituting this back into the constraint give $-\frac{\lambda -1}{2} = k/n$. Thus we have $x_i=k/n$.

Comment: Note that minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(x_i-1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - k$ is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$, so obviously the answer will be the same as the answer to your earlier question.

Comment: No (number-theory) here. Cancelled the tag.

Comment: Thijs, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, your usage of the Lagrange multipliers rule is correct.